# How can I cancel -[UIScrollView zoomToRect:animated:]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, animation, uiscrollview

Let's say I have called `-[UIScrollView zoomToRect:animated:]` with an animation value of `YES`. How can I immediately cancel this animation, so that it is as if it had never happened?

I call this method in some unit tests and want to reset its effects for when the next test runs. If this method can't be cancelled, then I will just dealloc my object in between tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Reset the zoom, set zoom scale to 1.0

```
[zoomScale setZoomScale:1.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[scrollView setZoomScale: scrollView.minimumZoomScale ];
```

would be better